# Плавный переход между фрагментами. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Создал проект с шаблоном Bottom Navigation Activity. Фрагменты, которые входят в нижнее меню, плавно сменяют друг друга. Что за эту плавность отвечает? Как её убрать?

Добавил свой фрагмент, который открывается при нажатии на кнопку, плавного открытия нет, как его добавить?

Comment: Что значит `плавно`? Попробуйте описать это и/или приложить видео. Многие никогда не видели как выглядят дефолтные проекты в студии и запускать их для попытки выяснить что именно вы имеете в виду мало кто будет)

Comment: Юрий, фрагмент, который открывается, у него как бы прозрачность меняется от 0 до 100%.

Comment: А, это должна быть анимация. В теории, вам надо просто добавить строчку для транзакции фрагмента. Типа как-то так: `ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);`

Comment: Юрий, спасибо большое, всё получилось)

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы добавить анимацию переключения фрагментов можно указать оную для транзакции:

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
```